# Not able to fetch data or queue data from FTP server in Azure cloud nifi server?

Tags: azure, ftp, cloud, apache-nifi, ftp-client

I am using FTP server which is working in local and able to fetch data from FTP server, but in the Azure cloud nifi server same FTP server is not fetching a single record from the particular FTP server. I am using ListFTP associated with FetchFTP nifi processor and used the same configuration whatever I used in local for ListFTP and FetchFTP nifi processors.

Can someone please suggest what is happening here. I checked firewall and even I disabled the firewall. That FTP server is running on Active connection mode. I tried but I'm not able to figure out the exact reason.

I am attaching the screenshots of my FTP processors configuration. One very important thing while using GetFTP server it is not fetching a single data after running hours of hours and even not a single exception or error. But with ListFTP and FetchFTP server it is showing exception after some 15 minutes interval that is "Failed to perform listing on remote host due to java.net.SocketException"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think once you go through your `conf/nifi.properties` file and check whether keystore certificate is enabled or disabled and if it is disabled then do it enable. 
Here you can check nifi configuration [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#configuration-best-practices).

Comment: I appreciate your reply I will try and then let you know whether it will work or not.